# Raspivid + FFMPEG + killall = :-)

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m using Raspivid and ffmpeg to record a stereo video with audio. It works fine.

```
raspivid -t 0 -n -w 1792 -h 896 -fps 20 -g 20 -ih -fl -b 8000000 -3d sbs -co -15 -fli auto -pf baseline  -o - | ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s32le -sample_rate 11025 -thread_queue_size 32k -i hw:1,0 -thread_queue_size 32k -framerate 20 -i - -f mp4 -c:v libx264  -b:a 64k -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

To stop the recording process (from node) I’m using:

```
killall -q raspivid ffmpeg
```

This works (makes test.mp4) BUT doesn’t let the Raspivid/ffmpeg finish the job completely. It immediately kills everything while it’s still finishing. There are usually about 5-10 seconds of rendering left to complete - so I lose these seconds from the killall .

What process can be triggered to stop this process yet let it finish rendering all frames of the mp4?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The issue was actually NOT related to the kill action. The real issue was related to the frame rate of the recording pipeline, which was 8 FPS. This was significantly improved by removing many superfluous tags in the pipeline, such as -thread_queue_size 32k, -c:v libx264 -b:a 64k and -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p.

This optimized pipeline now records at 33 FPS solid, which is great!

raspivid -t 0 -n -w 1792 -h 896 -fps 20 -g 20 -ih -fl -b 8000000 -3d sbs -co -15 -fli auto -pf baseline -o - | ffmpeg -y -f alsa -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s32le -sample_rate 11025 -i hw:1,0 -framerate 20 -i - -f mp4 -c:v copy -b:a 64k test.mp4